# TemplateHaskell's addDependentFile doesn't work when the file doesn't exist

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I want my TemplateHaskell expression recompiled when the dependent file changes and in case it doesn't exist, use a fallback file. But once the dependent file is created I want to also recompile.

The following is an example code:

```hs
import Control.Monad.Cont (MonadIO (liftIO))
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax (Lift (liftTyped))
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Compat (SpliceQ, liftSplice)
import System.Directory (doesFileExist)


myFn :: SpliceQ String
myFn = 
   let filePath = "...."
       fallbackPath = "...."
   in do
      liftSplice (addDependentFile filePath >>= liftTyped)
      exists <- liftIO (doesFileExist filePath)
      let path = if exists then filePath else fallbackPath
      ... -- Then e.g. simply load the file using `path` and return contents
```

The problem is that `addDependentFile` fails in case the file doesn't exist. And in case I run `addDependentFile` only when `exists` is `True`, it doesn't recompile once the file gets created.

How to achieve this?
(In case it's not possible to achieve, I also have a workaround in mind - i.e. once the dependent file doesn't exist and fallback is used, let it recompile every time. Is at least this possible to do?)

Answer (score 0):

Since Template Haskell can only register static files as dependencies, you probably need to configure your build system one level up, using `Setup.hs` hooks, as described here in the docs: [Cabal User Guide: More complex packages](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cabal-package.html#more-complex-packages).

Comment: Hmm, I would be curious to see an example.